# How to validate multiple fields selectively using a common class in PHP laravel while returning all errors

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

Just started with my first PHP laravel project, and I have this

**UserRepository.php**

```
public function validateNewEmail(Request $request, $emailName) {
    $request->validate([
        $emailName => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users'],
    ]);
}

public function validateNewPassword(Request $request, $passwordName) {
    $request->validate(
        // rule
        [
            $passwordName => ['required', 'min:8', 
                    'regex: // some long long regex'
        ],
        // message
        [
            $passwordName.".regex" => "Your new password must be more than 8 characters long, should contain at-least 1 uppercase, 1 lowercase, 1 numeric and 1 special character.",
        ]
    );
}

// Usr Id is by itself as it might be optional in registering.
public function validateNewUsrId(Request $request, $userIdName) {
    $request->validate([
        $userIdName => 'required|unique:users',
    ]);
}
```

And I can then use this repository easily like this in my controller.

```
$this->userRepository->validateNewEmail($request, "email");
$this->userRepository->validateNewPassword($request, "password");
$this->userRepository->validateNewUsrId($request, "usr_id");
```

The reason is because there might be multiple controllers that use the same rules, thus putting them in one place is better

However, I realised that this **method does not work because it returns the first error only**. For example when both the email and password is wrong, only the email error gets returned to the frontend.

What is the best way to achieve what I want? I want to put all my validation/rules in one place to be reused.

My first solution is this: Each function returns the error MessageBag which is then joined together. I will use `return $validator->errors();` to return the MessageBag which can be found here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#retrieving-the-first-error-message-for-a-field

However I slightly dislike it because then in order to check for whether an error occured, I would need to check if MessageBag is empty and then throw an error which seems a little weird.

The other way I thought of is to return the **rules** instead, so that I can join them in my controller and then validate all in one go. This seems better but I have to combine the **error messages** as well, which can be a little tricky if there are multiple (since the key is not fixed, see the code `$passwordName.".regex"` for example.), as I will need to update the key to each message.

The best way for me, is if I could return a validator for each function, and then use some sort of Validate::ValidateAll function? Is that possible?

How is this implemented usually?

Comment: `php artisan make:rule` https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: Also you should be using form request validation. Validation in controller is a very outdated method.

Comment: Also note Laravel has built-in support for all common password validation scenarios. You should use these whenever possible instead of trying to write your own with regular expressions. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-passwords

Comment: @miken32 I see, the form request validation seems like a good way to do it. Only downside is that every controller has to use the same name for a particular field. I can't name one "password" and another "pwd" for example. But I guess that is okay. Just checking, so if I want to have separate password, email and name requests, I have to make 3 different request classes yes? Because for example registering might require email, but changing password doesn't.

Comment: Not necessarily, you could make use of the `required_without_all` rule. So `password` is `required_without_all:email,name`, etc. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-required-without-all

Comment: Your question says "this method does not work because it returns the first error only." But you just commented "if I want to have separate... requests." So are you validating one field at a time or multiple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern Laravel applications typically use [form request validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#form-request-validation). With this approach, Laravel handles all the validation and returns error messages automatically. Simply write your form request class, and then use it in place of `Request` in your controller methods:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules\Password;

class MyFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => [
                'required',
                Password::min(8)->mixedCase()->numbers()->symbols()
            ],
            'usrid' => ['required', 'unique:users'],
        ];
    }
}
```

```php
public method store(MyFormRequest $request)
{
    // $request has been validated, no further checking needed
}
```

Note I'm using Laravel's [built-in password validation rules](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#validating-passwords) instead of relying on a "long long regex."